# Using a callback while dispatching actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am trying to make a GET request for some data.
Here is my action call.

```
componentDidMount() {
     this.props.fetchData(() => {
         this.setState({ isLoading: false });
     });
}
```

Prior to completion I'd like to display "Loading..." momentarily as the fetch request is making it's trip. I'm using a callback for this and setting my local state. 
Here is my action creator with a 'callback'.

```
export function fetchData(callback) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(`/api/fetchsomething`)
            .then(() => callback())
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    }
}
```

And here is that same function above but dispatching the action so that I can receive as props and render to my ui.

```
export function fetchData(callback) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(`/api/fetchsomething`)
            .then((response) => dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload: response }))
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    }
}
```

My question is how do you make the callback and dispatch the action in the same action creator function? Is that even good practice?

Comment: If all you want to do is set a loading state till the response is available, you can actually dispatch an action before making the async request that set the loading state in redux store, and clear it when you get the response

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => {
    // ensuring that you make the API request only 
    // after the local state `isLoading` is set to `true`
    this.props.fetchData().then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  });
}
```

and, `fetchData` would be defined as follows

```
export function fetchData(callback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get(`/api/fetchsomething`)
      .then((response) => dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload: response }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  }
}
```

If you're using the `redux-thunk` middleware to use asynchronous actions, then these actions will return `Promise`s; so you can set your component's local state after that `Promise` resolves.

Comment: Thanks for this option.

Answer (score 0):

In the component:

```
.....
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
}
....

export default connect((state) => ({loading: state.loading, data: state.data}))(Component);
```

In the actions, you should do :

```
....
export function fetchData() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCHING_DATA});     //dispatch an action for loading state to set it to true

    return axios.get(`/api/fetchsomething`)
      .then((response) => dispatch({ type: DATA_FETCHED, payload: response }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  }
}
....
```

In the reducer, you should do :

```
....
case 'FETCHING_DATA':
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
    } 

case 'DATA_FETCHED':
    return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
        loading: false,
    } 
    ....
```

I personally feel that you shouldn't put any `business logic` in your component because it can cause some problems later when you want to refactor your app. This means that there shouldn't be any `.then` in your component and everything should be guided through redux (if there is some side effects in your app). So, you should control your `loading` state from redux itself and not inside the component.

Comment: Thanks for this option.